# Which mathematical curve describes sun movement on the sky during the year?

Tags: curves

There is a kind of photography that is called a [solargraphy](http://jessethompsonphotographer.com/solargraphy) which is essentially a photo with a giant exposure period — half of the year or so. I noticed that sun trajectories on the sky are very similar to mathematical curves, take a look:

[image]

[image]

Is sun movement from the point of the viewer on the Earth described by the mathematical law? By which one?

Comment: There are a lot of different curves, we can check it in the same link you posted.

Comment: The obvious answer to me is yes, because there are level sets which can be plotted. As far as what you are seeing, I'd ask an astronomer or physicist to explain exactly what is being seen. Remember, the night sky is a not a Cartesian plot!

Comment: Each one of those curves looks like a [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with slightly different parameters.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma)? But this is probably a question for [astronomy.SE](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com) and not here.

Comment: Solargraphy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-exposure_photography#Solargraphy and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_path and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun